# change the order js inserts the text into the html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to change the where the js inserts the text into the html currently it is always putting at the end and I need it to insert it at the start and push the others down. That is, if it inserts

```
<li>1</li>, <li>2</li>, <li>3</li>
```

it will keep it in that order I need the last one to always be listed first like

```
<li>3</li>, <li>2</li>, <li>1</li>
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="stackleft" id="p1_stack"></div>
    <div class="stackright" id="p2_stack"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
function drawStack(isFinal) {
    var stackLength = Oscore[currentPlayer].stack.length;
    var temp = "";
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < stackLength; i++) {
        var val = Oscore[currentPlayer].stack[i];
        temp += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
        tot += val;
    }

    //if(!isFinal){
    //temp = '<div class="workingScore">'+scoreTemp+'</div><br>' + temp;
    //}

    var writeSore = document.form1.game.value - tot;
    writeit(writeSore, currentPlayer + "_score");
    writeit(temp, currentPlayer + "_stack");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
temp = "<li>" + val + "</li>" + temp;
```

You were missing a quote in the code shown too (now fixed by someone's edit), probably wouldn't have worked at all as written originally.

EDIT: I think I like the loop backward approach better, but it's up to you what you think is clearest.

Answer (score 3):

Try to loop backward:

```
for (var i = stackLength; i--; ) {
    var val = Oscore[currentPlayer].stack[i];
    temp += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
    tot += val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `prepend()` from JQuery.....

Comment: He does not seem to be using jQuery, so this is not very helpful : )